# Allowing restricted useres wifi access

Tags: wireless

Is there a way to allow restricted users/accounts the ability to add a wifi profile and connect to a wifi network?

Comment: What if you disable the Network Manager?

Comment: That sounds like that would work-that would in turn allow users to manage wifi networks without admin access?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the wireless configuration (of each network) that says "Available to all users". Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: No, I wanted to give the users the ability to add their own networks without administrator access.